# Scalar line integrals, line integrals of vector fields are independent of parametrization.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

1.To evaluate the line integral $\int\limits_{C}fds$ for a continuous function $f$ on a region containing a smooth curve $C$, we find a parameterization of $C$, $r(t), a\leq t\leq b$ and compute $\int\limits_{C}fds=\int\limits_{a}^{a}f(r(t))\mid r'(t)\mid dt$.

2.To evaluate the line integral $\int\limits_{C}F\cdot Tds$ for a vector field $F$ that is continuous on a region containing a smooth oriented curve $C$ parameterized by arc length, we find a parameterization of $C$, $r(t), a\leq t\leq b$(the orientation is NOT reversed.) and compute $\int\limits_{C}F\cdot Tds=\int\limits_{a}^{a}f(r(t))\cdot r'(t)dt$ where $\cdot$ means the dot product.

Reading the process of deriving the above methods, I assumed that Scalar line integrals, line integrals of vector fields are independent of parametrization. Is that correct?

Comment: That is right.  The chain rule tells you that the definite integral doesn't change.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!